# How can I synchronize TSC across cores?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, assembly

Using:

```
inline uint64_t rdtsc()
{
  uint32_t cycles_high;
  uint32_t cycles_low;

  asm volatile ("CPUID\n\t"
      "RDTSC\n\t"
      "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
      "mov %%eax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low)::
      "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
  return ( ((uint64_t)cycles_high << 32) | cycles_low );
}
```

thread 1 running

```
while(globalIndex < COUNT)
{
  while(globalIndex %2 == 0 && globalIndex < COUNT)
    ;
  cycles[globalIndex][0] = rdtsc();
  cycles[globalIndex][1] = cpuToBindTo;
  __sync_add_and_fetch(&globalIndex,1);
}
```

thread 2 running

```
while(globalIndex < COUNT)
{
  while(globalIndex %2 == 1 && globalIndex < COUNT)
    ;
  cycles[globalIndex][0] = rdtsc();
  cycles[globalIndex][1] = cpuToBindTo;
  __sync_add_and_fetch(&globalIndex,1);
}
```

i am seeing

```
CPU     rdtsc()         t1-t0
11 = 5023231563212740   990
03 = 5023231563213730   310
11 = 5023231563214040   990
03 = 5023231563215030   310
11 = 5023231563215340   990
03 = 5023231563216330   310
11 = 5023231563216640   990
03 = 5023231563217630   310
11 = 5023231563217940   990
03 = 5023231563218930   310
11 = 5023231563219240   990
03 = 5023231563220230   310
11 = 5023231563220540   990
03 = 5023231563221530   310
11 = 5023231563221840   990
03 = 5023231563222830   310
11 = 5023231563223140   990
03 = 5023231563224130   310
11 = 5023231563224440   990
03 = 5023231563225430   310
11 = 5023231563225740   990
03 = 5023231561739842   310
11 = 5023231561740152   990
03 = 5023231561741142   310
11 = 5023231561741452   12458
03 = 5023231561753910   458
11 = 5023231561754368   1154
03 = 5023231561755522   318
11 = 5023231561755840   982
03 = 5023231561756822   310
11 = 5023231561757132   990
03 = 5023231561758122   310
11 = 5023231561758432   990
03 = 5023231561759422   310
```

I'm not sure how I received a pong of 12458, but was wondering why i was seeing 310-990-310 instead of 650-650-650.  I thought that tsc was suppose to be synchronized across cores.  my constant_tsc cpu flag is on.

Answer (score 1):

What are you running this code on? TSC synchronization is supposed to be done in the OS/kernel and is hardware dependent. For instance, you might pass a flag like `powernow-k8.tscsync=1` to the kernel boot parameters via your bootloader.

You need to search for the correct TSC synchronization method for your combination of OS and hardware. By and large, this entire thing is automated - I wouldn't be surprised if you're running on a custom kernel or non i686 hardware?

If you search on Google with the correct terms, you'll find a lot of resources such as mailing list discussions on this topic. For instance, here's [one algorithm being discussed](http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2005-May/006037.html) (though apparently it's not a good one). However, it's not something that userland developers should be worried with - this is arcane sorcery that only kernel devs need to worry their heads with.

Basically, it's the OS' job, at boot time, to synchronize the TSC counters between all the different processors and/or cores on an SMP machine, within a certain margin of error. If you're seeing numbers that are that wildly off, there's something wrong with the TSC sync and your time would be better spent finding out why your OS hasn't synced the TSCs correctly rather than trying to implement your own TSC sync algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a NUMA memory architecture?  The global counter could be located in RAM that is a couple hops away for one of the CPUs and local for the other.  You can test this by fixing your threads to cores on the same NUMA node.

EDIT: I was guessing this since the performance was CPU specific.

EDIT: As to synchronizing the TSC.  I am not aware of a an easy way, which is not to say that there isn't one!  What would happen if you took core 1 as the reference clock, and then compared it to core 2?  If you did that comparison many times and took the minimum, you might have a good approximation.  This should handle the case when you get preempted in the middle of a comparison.

Comment: I am running this on a 2 socket server using cpus 3 and 11 which are on socket 2. lscpu | grep NUMA returns
'
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10
  NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11
'

Comment: Just for the hell of it...what happens when you run the threads on different CPUs other than 3 and 11?

Comment: Is globalindex volatile? Although, for globals, volatile is probably not necessary.  Are you compiling with -O3?  Also, to get cleaner stats we can sum up the stats in arrays that don't pollute the cache lines for the other thread.  Use a struct to hold the cpu/time and then add a couple bogus fields so it adds up to 64 bytes.  Then declare cycles with __attribute((align(64)).  After that every update should be on a nice clean cache line.